# Angular 2 Dart: use of NgModule in dart

Tags: angular, dart

I am developing a modular web Angular 2 dart application, where modules are  interchangeable and each carry  its own responsibility/function. I started with the following link:

https://angular.io/docs/dart/latest/guide/ngmodule.html, but the documentation is not finished... I continued with the TypeScript reference, where i learned @NgModule

I tried implementing @NgModule but couldn't even find it in the dart packages source code, how can i accomplish grouping of Multiple Components, Directives, their services, and pipes in Dart? Is there anything like @NgModule as in TypeScript?

I tried bootstraping multiple App Root Components, which worked, but i don't believe it is a right solution to the problem. And if not how can i share data in between?

in my main.dart i have:

```
    import 'package:angular2/platform/browser.dart';
    import 'package:test/app_component.dart';
    import 'package:test/app1_component.dart';

    main() {
       bootstrap(AppComponent);
       bootstrap(App1Component);
    }
```

Where AppComponent and App1Component are root app components; Would this be equivalent to @NgModule in https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Angular2 Dart doesn't have the concept of modules. `NgModule` was introduced mainly to allow lazy loading of parts of the application. Since Dart allows lazy loading (called [deferred loading](http://news.dartlang.org/2014/08/dart-16-adds-support-for-deferred.html) in Dart) by default, there was no need to implement `NgModule`.

Here's an article about lazy loading in Angular2 Dart: https://medium.com/@matanlurey/lazy-loading-with-angular-dart-14f58004f988#.6ryctgg5q

There's also a repo that illustrates how you can lazily load specific routes: https://github.com/kulshekhar/angular-dart-routing-lazy-loading

Using this, you can use interchangeable components in places where you were using interchangeable modules

Answer (score 0):

AngularDart does use a Module https://angulardart.dev/glossary#M

Comment: These are a different concept, they just happen to have the same name.